# Checkbox Value in textbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textbox, return-value

Here i attached my java script as well as html form in that i can not get value of first checkbox and getting next checkbox's value.Please help me out in this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkboxCount = 0;
var inputTags = document.getElementsByName('pr');
for (var i=0, length = inputTags.length; i <= length ;i++) {
    if (inputTags[i].type == 'checkbox') {
     checkboxCount++;
 }
 document.write(checkboxCount);
}


function ATHD() {
    var totalValue = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < checkboxCount; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(i).checked)
        totalValue += inputTags[i].value + ';';
    }
    document.getElementById("hdnValues").value = totalValue;
    document.getElementById("showValues").value = totalValue;
```

}

```
<form>
Wraps: <input type="text" id="showValues" name="wrap" /><br />
        <input onClick="ATHD()" id="1" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="Password               Reset" />*Password Reset<br />
        <input onClick="ATHD()" id="2" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="Password   Setup" />*Password Setup<br />
        <input onClick="ATHD()" id="3" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="Firmware   Upgrade (if applicable)" />*Firmware                                       Upgrade (if applicable)<br />
 <input onClick="ATHD()" id="4" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="Local Access Setup" />*Local Access Setup<br />
<input onClick="ATHD()" id="5" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="Remote Access Setup" />*Remote Access Setup<br />
<input onClick="ATHD()" id="6" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="Mobile Access Setup" />*Mobile Access Setup<br />
<input onClick="ATHD()" id="7" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="Recording Schedule Setup" />*Recording Schedule     Setup<br />
<input onClick="ATHD()" id="8" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="How to playback video" />*How to playback video<br />
<input onClick="ATHD()" id="9" type="checkbox" name="pr" value="How to convert video" />*How to convert video<br />
<br />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnValues" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you have defined the global variable **checkboxCount** as 0

So when the for loops runs for the very first time the condition is not satisfied and the code does not get executed.

The condition evaluates to

for(i=1;i<0;i++) which is erroneous please look into this you be able to solve it

Comment: so according to you what should i do?i am not getting any idea...please help me..

Comment: can you please elaborate your question im not getting what are you trying to achieve

Comment: actually i want multiple selected check box values in textbox where i define the variable checkboxCount?

Comment: no, the values of the check box which are checked in the textbox or textarea